# Pass function argument as code block

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I have been searching but there is no easy "search string" for the seemingly easy question I have.

```
def foo( f: (String) => String ){println(f("123"))}
foo{_+"abc"} //works

def bar( f :() => String ){println(f())}
bar{"xyz"} // why does this not work?

def baz( f: => String ){println(f)}
baz{"xyz"} //works
```

Why does the second (`bar`) not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second `baz` works because it's not a function literal, but a call-by-name parameter. Basically what it does is delaying the moment of argument computation until it's needed in the program. You can also read about this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986557/scala-call-by-name-confusion) question.
As for `bar` you just need to pass a function like `bar{() => "xyz"}`

Comment: is the `baz` method then the recommended approach for when you want to define structures such as `try{...}`?

Comment: @jfisher Actually in Scala try catch is not recomended at all. There is more functional approach to with [Try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986557/scala-call-by-name-confusion). As for call-by-name, it is helpfull when you have some big computaion and you are not sure wether you need it or not, for example in if-else expression

Comment: What i meant what if i want to create try-alike structures such as `monitor{...}` `mutex{...}` `instrument{...}` and so on. Would the "baz" approach than be the best for those kind of "language" structures?

Answer (score 1):

`bar` accepts a function that takes no arguments and returns `String`. You gave it just a `String`. To make it work:

```
bar{() => "xyz"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is special to parameterless functions/blocks.

```
object Fs2 {
  def f0=1
  def f0_1()=1
}

object Main extends App {
  println(Fs2.f0)
  //println(Fs2.f0()) wont compile
  println(Fs2.f0_1)
  println(Fs2.f0_1())
}
```

Unit "()" is optional for f0_1. Adding it to f0 will cause an error. f0 does not accept any parameter. Unit itself is a parameter declaring there is no parameter. Fs2.f0 corresponds to baz, Fs2.f0() corresponds to bar.